# Когда нужно использовать шейдеры?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, шейдеры

Я разрабатываю pet-проект небольшого gui движка, и попутно изучаю opengl. В туториалах я наткнулся на тему шейдеров. Что такое шейдер я понял, но не понял когда их применять. Есть ли вообще смысл использовать шейдеры для gui? Если да, то приведить пожалуйста пример когда это необходимо

Comment: В "современном" (3.х) OpenGL вообще нет рисования без шейдеров. Думаю все зависит от желаемой версии GL. Например, у ImGui две разные реализации рисования через GL, для нового и для старого.